# How to make Twitter API call through curl in unix

Tags: api, curl, twitter

I would like to pull the data from Twitter REST API. I have created the consumer key, secret and Access token, secret. I have tried with "Test OAuth", it generates a CURL command but if I change any one parameter then it is giving the below error.
Message: {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}

Now I would like to call the twitter API using CURL in shell script for different screenNames.

I want a sample command some thing like mentioned below

curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json' --data 'count=2&screen_name=aswin' APIKEY:"xxxxxx",Acesstoken:"yyyyyyyy"

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Aswin

Comment: Assuming you have ballerina(http://ballerinalang.org/) installed on your box, you can create a ballerina script to do the twitter work for you using its built in support for it and call it from within a shell script or shell itself. http://ballerinalang.org/docs/api/0.8/org.wso2.ballerina.connectors.twitter.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because most twitter requests require calculating the oauth signature, you should either write a client yourself or reuse an existing command line client.

1. https://github.com/twitter/twurl
2. https://github.com/sferik/t
3. https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/wiki (Mac focused/cross service)

As you saw any change to the request will generally invalidate the query, and even time is one of the inputs.

Comment: I need to do it only in Twitter Rest API

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer.

```
curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json' \
     --data 'count=2&screen_name=twitterapi' \
     --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", oauth_nonce="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB", oauth_signature="CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1471672391", oauth_token="DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD", oauth_version="1.0"'
```

Comment: Do we have to generate our own nonces and signature? I don't see them in the API settings.

Answer (score 3):

Since your specific query doesn't require a user context you can use Application only authentication to make this request.  The bearer token won't change per request so it should allow you to keep using curl.

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only

n.b. it won't work for all endpoints, but should for the case you listed.